# How can I generate typesafe config (Hocon) file dynamically in scala (generate config file)

Tags: scala, typesafe, hocon

I want to generate Hocon config dynamically.

**Input** Map  and

**output** file with below content

```
block{
key1 : value
key2 : value
}

Trying to read map
     var myMap = new util.HashMap[String,AnyRef]()
     val myConfig = ConfigFactory.parseMap(myMap)

myConfig.toString print below
Config(SimpleConfigObject({"key":"value"}))
```

not able to figure out how to extract conf from it

I tried below option but it prints in JSON format

```
val finalConfig : String =
      myConfig.root().render( ConfigRenderOptions.defaults())
println(finalConfig)
```

Any other approach to generate conf so that nested structure can be supported ?

Edit: Found solution
Nested config can be created using ConfigFactory.withValue
https://marcinkubala.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/typesafe-config-hocon/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your problem well...

But it seems to me, that you only need to format your `Map` as a **HOCON**-like `String`.
Which you can latter write to a file.

Hope this code snippet is what you are looking for:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

def toHocon(map: java.util.Map[String, AnyRef]): String =
  map
   .asScala
   .map { case (key, value) => s"$key : $value" }
   .mkString("block{\n\t", "\n\t", "\n}")
```

*(I used one **tab** character for the indentation, you may replace it with more **tabs**, or with a fixed number of white spaces)*.

Comment: I like this solution but it may not support nested Hocon creation. Any inputs if I want to create nested json in scala like p1{key: value , c1{key1 : value1}}

Comment: @user2895589 Thanks for accepting my answer, but I really do not answered your question. You should add your own answer and accept that one instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[kxbmap/configs](https://github.com/kxbmap/configs)**

This supports `play-json` out of the box. I use it to map whole configurations directly to `case classes`.

So your example would look like:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import configs.Configs

val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("""
  block{
    key1 : value
    key2 : value
  }
  """)

config.get[Map[String, String]("block")
```

Comment: Hi@pme my input a map and I want to print confing file. I want to generate config file

Comment: oh sorry - I just used that library yesterday - so I was a bit too enthusiastic to use it;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below :

```
    myConfig.root().render(com.typesafe.config.ConfigRenderOptions.concise())
```